# Find nodes containing string split over 2 tags

Tags: xpath

is there a way to get nodes containing a specific string which is split over 2 tags. I tried this but it doesn't work. I can't manage to ignore `foreign` tag.

```
$crawler->filterXPath('//p/text()[contains(., "caractère a priori")]');
```

```
<p>leur caractère <foreign xml:lang="lat">a priori</foreign>, soit..</p>
```

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Is your expected output `leur caractère a priori soit`?

Comment: Dont know what output I want yet.  Anyway, Dan Gardner answer seems to work !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below XPath should work for you, it will return only `<p>` nodes which contain the text specified in the contains statement. I've expanded the example a bit, for me to test, and included a fiddle [here](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/75c98eb1ece85f395fb43813d6ad8500).

**XPath:**

`div/p[contains(., 'caractère a priori')]`

**Input**

```
<div>
    <p>leur caractère <foreign xml:lang="lat">a priori</foreign>, soit..</p>
    <p>leur poisson <foreign xml:lang="lat">a priori</foreign>, soit..</p>
</div>
```

**Output**

```
<p>leur caractère <foreign xml:lang="lat">a priori</foreign>, soit..</p>
```

Hopefully that give you enough to go on!